# Returning automatic local objects in C++

Tags: c++, return, copy-constructor

I'm trying to understand some aspects of C++.

I have written this short programme to show different ways of returning objects from functions in C++:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

// A simple class with only one private member.
class Car{
     private:
        int maxSpeed;
     public:
        Car( int );
        void print();
        Car& operator= (const Car &);
        Car(const Car &);
 };

 // Constructor
 Car::Car( int maxSpeed ){
    this -> maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    cout << "Constructor: New Car (speed="<<maxSpeed<<") at " << this << endl;
 }

 // Assignment operator
 Car& Car::operator= (const Car &anotherCar){
    cout << "Assignment operator: copying " << &anotherCar << " into " << this << endl;
    this -> maxSpeed = anotherCar.maxSpeed;
    return *this;
 }

 // Copy constructor
 Car::Car(const Car &anotherCar ) {
    cout << "Copy constructor: copying " << &anotherCar << " into " << this << endl;
    this->maxSpeed = anotherCar.maxSpeed;
 }

 // Print the car.
 void Car::print(){
    cout << "Print: Car (speed=" << maxSpeed << ") at " << this << endl;
 }

 // return automatic object (copy object on return) (STACK)
 Car makeNewCarCopy(){
    Car c(120);
    return c; // object copied and destroyed here
 }

// return reference to object (STACK)
Car& makeNewCarRef(){
    Car c(60);
    return c; // c destroyed here, UNSAFE!
    // compiler will say: warning: reference to local variable ‘c’ returned
 }

// return pointer to object (HEAP)
Car* makeNewCarPointer(){
    Car * pt = new Car(30);
    return pt; // object in the heap, remember to delete it later on!
 }

int main(){
    Car a(1),c(2);
    Car *b = new Car(a);
    a.print();
    a = c;
    a.print();

    Car copyC = makeNewCarCopy(); // safe, but requires copy
    copyC.print();

    Car &refC = makeNewCarRef(); // UNSAFE
    refC.print();

    Car *ptC = makeNewCarPointer(); // safe
    if (ptC!=NULL){
        ptC -> print();
        delete ptC;
    } else {
        // NULL pointer
    }
}
```

The code doesn't seem to crash, and I get the following output:

```
Constructor: New Car (speed=1) at 0x7fff51be7a38
Constructor: New Car (speed=2) at 0x7fff51be7a30
Copy constructor: copying 0x7fff51be7a38 into 0x7ff60b4000e0
Print: Car (speed=1) at 0x7fff51be7a38
Assignment operator: copying 0x7fff51be7a30 into 0x7fff51be7a38
Print: Car (speed=2) at 0x7fff51be7a38
Constructor: New Car (speed=120) at 0x7fff51be7a20
Print: Car (speed=120) at 0x7fff51be7a20
Constructor: New Car (speed=60) at 0x7fff51be79c8
Print: Car (speed=60) at 0x7fff51be79c8
Constructor: New Car (speed=30) at 0x7ff60b403a60
Print: Car (speed=30) at 0x7ff60b403a60
```

Now, I have the following questions:

- Is makeNewCarCopy safe? Is the local object being copied and destroyed at the end of the function? If so, why isn't it calling the overloaded assignment operator? Does it call the default copy constructor?
- My guts tell me to use `makeNewCarPointer` as the most usual way of returning objects from a C++ function/method. Am I right?

Comment: 1) you get copy elision. 2) No, the most natural way is to return by value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is makeNewCarCopy safe? Is the local object being copied and destroyed
>   at the end of the function? If so, why isn't it calling the overloaded
>   assignment operator? Does it call the default copy constructor?

The *important* question here is "Is makeNewCarCopy safe?"  The answer to that question is, "yes."  You are making a copy of the object and returning that copy by-value.  You do not attempt to return a reference to a local automatic object, which is a common pitfall among newbies, and that is good.

The answers to the other parts of this question are philisophically less important, although once you know how to do this safely they may become critically important in production code.  You may or may not see construction and destruction of the local object.  In fact, you probably won't, especially when compiling with optimizations turned on.  The reason is because the compiler knows that you are creating a temporary and returning that, which in turn is being copied somewhere else.  The temporary becomes meaningless in a sense, so the compiler skips the whole bothersome create-copy-destroy step and simply constructs the new copy *directly* in the variable where it's ultimately intended.  This is called [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).  Compilers are allowed to make any and all changes to your program so long as the observable behavior is the same as if no changes were made (see: [As-If Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)) even in cases where the copy constructor has side-effects (see: [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)) .

> My guts tell me to use makeNewCarPointer as the most usual way of
>   returning objects from a C++ function/method. Am I right?

No.  Consider copy elision, as I described it above.  All contemporary, major compilers implement this optimization, and do a very good job at it.  So if you can copy by-value as efficiently (at least) as copy by-pointer, is there any benefit to copy by-pointer with respect to performance?

The answer is no.  These days, you generally want to return by-value unless you have *compelling need not to*.  Among those compelling needs are when you need the returned object to outlive the "scope" in which it was created -- but *not* among those is performance.  In fact, dynamic allocation can be significantly more expensive time-wise than automatic (ie, "stack") allocation.

Comment: The "return value optimization" is actually the one case where the compiler is allowed to break the "as if" rule. Consider `Car x = makeNewCarCopy();` That's an explicit copy there that the "as if" rule is not allowed to remove.

Comment: @Fozi:  Um, I'm not sure about that.  The as-if rule states that compilers can make any changes to the program whatsoever, so long as the observable behavior of the resulting program is the same as-if no changes were made.  In general, lack of copy is not an observable behavior.

Comment: Yes but the expected behavior here would be that the copy constructor is called. The return value optimization explicitly frees the compiler from this obligation. Please see the Wiki article linked in my answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling Fozi is right, as-if doesn't have to apply in RVO. You can test it by placing printout statements in copy constructors and copy assignment operators.

Comment: @Fozi The return value optimization is _not_ the only place where the compiler may break the 'as if' rule. You can take a look at 12.8/32 to see the actual rules for copy elision, but perhaps the easiest thing is to look at the example given in that paragraph; It shows code that exactly matches your `Car x = makeNewCarCopy();` and explicitly says that the copy can be elided. This is implemented by gcc, clang, and vc++. [Demo](http://ideone.com/pMhN9V)

Comment: @bames53 I'm not sure how 12.8/32 is relevant here: it's about how the overload resolution should work (Which copy-constructor should be picked?). It does seem to use RVO in the example. That said, there might very well be other cases that allow to break the "as if" rule in the standard that I don't know of. I should have written "is one case where".

Comment: @Fozi Sorry, that should be 12.8/31 (in the C++11 standard). The example it gives is in part `Thing t2 = f();` and it says "Here the criteria for elision can be combined to eliminate two calls to the copy constructor of class Thing" and it directly contradicts your statement "That's an explicit copy there that the "as if" rule _is not allowed to remove_ [emphasis added]."

Comment: @bames53 I think 12.8/31 _is_ RVO. (Is it? Wiki says 12.8/15 but that seems to be something else.) BTW I'm referring to n3485 here.

Comment: @Fozi Wikipedia is referring to C++03 so the paragraph number is different. 12.8/31 [c++11] describes copy elision, including but not limited to RVO. My point is simply that in your example `Car x = makeNewCarCopy();` you say that the copy is not allowed to be elided, but in fact it is.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `makeNewCarCopy` is safe. Theoretically there will be a copy made as the function exits, however because of the [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) the compiler is allowed to remove the copy.

In practice this means that `makeNewCarCopy` will have a hidden first parameter which is a reference to an uninitialized `Car` and the constructor call inside `makeNewCarCopy` will actually initialize the `Car` instance that resides outside of the function's stack frame.

As to your second question: Returning a pointer that has to be freed is not the preferred way. It's unsafe because the implementation detail of how the function allocated the `Car` instance is leaked out and the caller is burdened with cleaning it up. If you need dynamic allocation then I suggest that you return an `std::shared_ptr<Car>` instead.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Car>` is far more often a better choice than `std::shared_ptr<Car>`.

Comment: @Yakk I find that `unique_ptr` is unnecessarily limiting and the only thing it is better at is the performance. I have never had a case where I was thinking "I really wished I used a `unique_ptr` here!". I only use `unique_ptr` if it never leaves the class/module, which this is not the case here.

Comment: The problem with `shared_ptr` is that that lifetime and ownership are now unclear.  In almost every situation, an object should be owned by exactly one other data structure: when an object is owned by more than one data structure, you tend to get the resource management equivalent of spaghetti code.  `shared_ptr` expresses shared management and ownership of an object's lifetime, which is a corner case, and should not be your default.  And yes, it lets you do far more things than `unique_ptr`, but many of those things are bad habits!

Comment: @Yakk I think we agree, but we have a misunderstanding in what the current scenario here is. I consider `makeNewCarCopy` a public library function that's task is to create instances of `Car`s. The usage of `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` says nothing about ownership, the architecture, the interface contracts, the object holding it does.

Comment: Yes, you can refuse to use any feature of `shared_ptr` that `unique_ptr` lacks, and pinky swear that nobody else modifying the code will do that either.  On the other hand, if you just use `unique_ptr`, the compiler tells you when you violate that guarantee.  Your default smart pointer should be a `unique_ptr`, as it moves errors from run time to compile time.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes `makeNewCarCopy` is safe. And in most cases it is effective as compiler can do certain optimizations like [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) (and that the reason you do not see assignment operator or copy ctor called) and/or [move semantics](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) added by C++11
- `makeNewCarPointer` can be very effective, but is is very dangerous at the same time. The problem is you can easily ignore return value and compiler will not produce any warnings. So at least you should return smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. But IMHO previous method is more preferred and would be at least not slower. Different story if you have to create object on heap by different reason.